# How can I use guava's MultiMap to split list of values

Tags: java, guava

Map is of type `Map<String, List<MyClass>>`
I have more than 100 objects of `MyClass` associated with Key.
I need to split it if it's more than 100.

For e.g.
Input is

```
Map<String, List<MyClass>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<MyClass>>();

myMap.put("ABC", [CustomObject1,CustomObject2,CustomObject3....CustomObject100...CustomObject110]);
```

& Output should be

```
myMap.put("ABC", [CustomObject1,CustomObject2,CustomObject3....CustomObject100]);
myMap.put("ABC", [CustomObject100,CustomObject101....CustomObject110]);
```

I thought of getting myMap.containsKey(string) and check size of list and then create new entry or add it in same.
I tried using guava's multimap but it returns Collection> when I try to get elements so not sure how to insert it. Or if there is any better option for this?

Comment: is the ordering of the elements important?  is that why the Collection returned by Guava MultiMap is causing you an issue?

Comment: Ordering is not important. Collection is json file which I am trying to covert to Map<String, List<MyClass>> but with restriction of size on List<MyClass>.

Comment: so once the "ABC" List reaches its maximum size of 100 you want to create a new List which replaces the existing list?  or you want the "ABC" key to reference 2 separate Lists?

Comment: "ABC" key to reference 2 separate Lists.

Comment: would it be acceptable to create a map of "ABC" to all the MyClass objects then partitiion them into chunks of 100 afterwards?

Comment: You mean split a map into multiple maps? This is what I need as output

Answer (score 0):

Try using Guava Lists.partition

```
Map<String, List<MyClass>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<MyClass>>();

myMap.put("ABC", [CustomObject1,CustomObject2,CustomObject3....CustomObject100...CustomObject110]);

Map<String, List<List<MyClass>>> output = myMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> Lists.partition(e.getValue(), 100)));
```